# VSCode is not pushing the code and not not throwing any error

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, sfdc, sfdc-migration-tool

Using command - **sfdx force:source:push** to push an application and a component.

it does not throw any error, but the components are not reflecting in the Developer console.

I have placed the package.xml with below config :

```
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <!-- Lightning Component -->
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>AuraDefinitionBundle</name>
    </types>   
<version>46.0</version>
</Package>
```

Also, I got message after push command as below:

```
Job ID | 0AfN0000017CdNmKAK
SOURCE PROGRESS | ████████████████████████████████████████ | 2/2 Components
=== Pushed Source
```

The scratch org is configured and is displaying on command

```
sfdx force:org:list --all
```

Someone please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe from the above question that you used only `sfdx force:source:push` and no flags at the end for deployment to the org.

The first thing I would suggest is to check your

```
> sfdx-project.json
```

file to check if the path to your source is correct.

Secondly, if you are using a package manifest (package.xml) file, then I recommend using the `sfdx force:source:deploy` command which has some flags that might help in your deployment process.

for eg:
if you have a package.xml file.

`sfdx force:source:deploy -x <path/to/package.xml> -u <orgAliasOrDefaultUsername>`

You can get more help from the documentation in the link given below

[sfdx source commands](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm)

Comment: sfdx force:source:deploy -x src/package.xml -u one    .... I have tried giving a path .. yet, I cant see the components in my developer console.. However.. I am getting a successful deploy message

Comment: {
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true
    }
  ],
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "49.0"
}

Comment: above is the content of sfdx-project.json

Comment: It is working now.. I had missed to Authenticate the org